# Installing PHPmyadmin with existing databases

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Seems like something easy to search for... but I couldn't find a clear answer. I currently have several existing MySQL databases and I would like to manage them with PHPmyadmin.. Running latest stable version of ubuntu. All of the tutorials I see are for fresh installs.. Is there anything I should look out for or any tutorials for installing phpmyadmin with existing databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you'll have to lookout for is ensuring your MySQL server allows remote connections.

See:
[How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Then you'll need to edit your config.inc.php file to add new hosts.

See:
https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_host

Comment: Thanks! MySQL showes it allows remote connections... Installing Phpmyadmin via the terminal shouldn't overwrite my current databases correct? I'm trying to make this go seamless with out any interruption

Comment: You should be fine, but if you don't have backups of your DB that's probably something you should have anyways! Look up the mysqldump command for backing up databases

Comment: Perfect.. I'm going to back up via the mysqldump command first.. the whole reason for installing the gui is for easier back ups every week.. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

run the command:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

u need to reconfigure it because lampp and xampp run phpmyadmin in different ports. So, its probably a ports conflicts. You can also open server.xml in your lampp and change the port no. which would be different from that of xampp. Then both mySQL(of xampp and lampp as well) will run.